# Can't restart Tomcat cartridge

Tags: mysql, tomcat, openshift

Less than 2 weeks ago I posted a question here about a problem in my OpenShift cartridge because I suddenly couldn't restart it anymore: [Error restarting Openshift MySQL cartridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197427/error-restarting-openshift-mysql-cartridge/22200421)

It was working fine and I didn't change anything on it but it simply stopped working. The only way I could "solve" the problem was deleting the gear and creating a new one, but now I have the same problem again :-(

This is really frustrating. I thought OpenShift was a realiable PaaS, but it looks like there's still a long way to go. I considering to buy the Enterprise plan, but I don't to pay for something that stops working out of nowhere.

By the way, here is the error log in case someone knows this time why this is happening:

```
Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
MySQL server failed to start:
140316 18:02:14 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/openshift/53104e375973cad496000022/mysql//log/mysql_error.log'.
140316 18:02:14 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/53104e375973cad496000022/mysql/data/
140316 18:02:17 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/53104e375973cad496000022/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
140316 18:02:14 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/53104e375973cad496000022/mysql/data/
140316 18:02:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140316 18:02:15 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140316 18:02:15 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140316 18:02:15 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140316 18:02:15 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140316 18:02:15  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
140316 18:02:17  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
140316 18:02:17 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
140316 18:02:17 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140316 18:02:17 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140316 18:02:17 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140316 18:02:17 [ERROR] Aborting

140316 18:02:17 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140316 18:02:17 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/53104e375973cad496000022/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for /var/lib/openshift/53104e375973cad496000022/mysql
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having the same issue as this user: [Can't add a MySQL cartridge on OpenShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525957/cant-add-a-mysql-cartridge-on-openshift)

It's a mysql bug we are working on a work around.

Comment: Hi. As I mentioned in my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197427/error-restarting-openshift-mysql-cartridge/22200421) I used the command "rhc app show --gears quota" and I'm using just 180 MB. I'll send an e-mail as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer, please check the linked question.