# Can't add a MySQL cartridge on OpenShift

Tags: mysql, openshift

I went to spin up a new application today and I'm running into some issues. I was able to add the PHP 5.4 cartridge just fine. I went to add a MySQL 5.5 cartridge and I received the following:

```
Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
MySQL server failed to start:
140320 03:05:46 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/openshift/532a883a4382ec501600043b/mysql//log/mysql_error.log'.
140320 03:05:46 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/532a883a4382ec501600043b/mysql/data/
140320 03:05:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/532a883a4382ec501600043b/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
140320 03:05:46 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/532a883a4382ec501600043b/mysql/data/
140320  3:05:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140320  3:05:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140320  3:05:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140320  3:05:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140320  3:05:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140320  3:05:48  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
140320  3:05:51  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
140320  3:05:51 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
140320  3:05:51 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140320  3:05:51 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140320  3:05:51 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140320  3:05:51 [ERROR] Aborting
140320  3:05:51 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
140320 03:05:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshif /532a883a4382ec501600043b/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/532a883a4382ec501600043b/mysql
```

I've seen [one other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197427/error-restarting-openshift-mysql-cartridge) that seems similar, but was when attempting to restart their app.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. hummm ...

Comment: are you able to fix this? can you share what you did to fix this issue, THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug (http://elenst.ru/mariadb/aio-max-nr-in-general-and-innodb-error-io_setup-failed-with-eagain-in-particular/) (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61575) we are looking into work arounds